# Unity 5 - Multiple Materials: Sprite Textures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if there's a way to use multiple textures on a single game object but only keep one active at a time. Maybe use of setActive(true/false)? I've been browsing around multiple forums and even Unity handbook but seen nothing relevant to what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's the deal. I'm pretty deep into programming at this point in my game. I have a LOT of scripts, layers, code, hp bars and children, etc.. attached to my 2D character which is nothing more than some 3D shapes I threw together (Because I REALLY SUCK at graphic design). Anyway, I created a texture and turned it into a material then put it on my character. Honestly, when I started this project, I planned on using this as a test only object. However, I learned the hard way that this was not such a good idea because transferring over chars after development is a horrible plan! Anyway, I created another material of the character facing different directions in hopes of using materials as my sprites animation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Define these variables. Just f.y.i. this is inside my movement script.

```
public Material rgtFace; // Is actually left facing .. derp
public Material lftFace;  // Is actually right facing herp ... 
public GameObject player;

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
       GetComponent<Renderer>().material = rgtFace;

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material = lftFace;
    }

}
```

Messed around and found the solution! Very simple code! Anyway, this case is closed :)